# triggering user journey from backend

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is it possible to edit the user profile without redirecting to the b2c frontend? I want to create an API endpoint called by the user which will update the value in b2c. I don't want to use graph API because there is a delay in propagating changes and it requires additional permission to edit users profiles.

Comment: What API do you expect to use if not the Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible without using the Graph API or the UI.

Eventual consistency will always play a factor, but if you need that real-time update you can create an intermediary API between your apps and B2C; this allows you to cache the user details (including from any profile updates).

Worth noting, the UI also does suffer from eventual consistency, just Microsoft attempts to handle it by throwing you at the same data centre for subsequent requests.